# add_filter - create_function pb in PHP8

Tags: filters

I have difficulties to make this little code compliant with PHP 8 :

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', create_function('', 'return "";') );
```

Any idea how to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `create_function` should be replaced with a [closure](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), like this:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', function() {
    return "";
});
```

But in your specific case, you don't even need that. WordPress has you covered already with a built-in function to use in a filter: [`__return_empty_string()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__return_empty_string/). So you can just write:

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', '__return_empty_string' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fuxia for your reply. It solved my pb. :)

Comment: @Seal20  Glad I could help. :) Please mark my post as accepted answer (the checkmark on the left), so your question doesn't come up in our _Unanswered_ list anymore.

Comment: Thank you again, I didn't knew ...That's done. Wish you a great day :)